# Transparent background

Tags: rendering, animation, transparency

I rendered an animation as an png image sequence and I wanted to put a picture in the sky background (the render would mask the picture behind it) in another video editing software. When I imported it to the editing software and put an image in the background, it didn't show up. What should I do to get a transparent background?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that simple
All you need to do is the select camera properties, then look down for Film and check transparent.

[image: Film]

Final result:
[image]

Comment: There is no "Film" there.